# Website - blocking view from none specified country locations

Tags: ip

I am looking for as reliable and accurate / quick means possible to add in some htaccess code to block visits to a website from countries / IPs which are not in the white listed list of countries I want to allow access for. I have looked at https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker which seems to offer a solution - for the 4 allowed countries I want to allow access - it has created a 4.1MB htaccess file! Will this mean slow access when someone attempts to view the site? I guess using a free service like this means the data is likely nowhere near comprehensive?

Does anyone have any suggestions on a good way to allow just visitors from a few countries access to a website?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the service you used basically tried tried to brute force the blacklist.  If you look into the htaccess file I'm sure you will be a long list of hard coded IP blocks.

In my opinion this is a terrible way to handle a geographic blacklist.  To your original question - there is no "most reliable, most accurate, and quickest" method.  Those are separate categories and you will need to preference one over the next.

For performance you could consider blacklisting at the routing level / dns server / proxy.  This obviously isn't going to be the quickest way in terms of performance.  There are Apache Modules that exist that allow you to use a local database to compare the incoming IP address with a list of known IP blocks from the blacklisted country.  One of the main issues with this is that you need to constantly update your database to take in new IP blocks.

In my opinion the "best" method to do this is a simple redirect at the application layer using server side code.  There exists several geographic API's where you can send in the IP or Hostname and get back a country of origin. An example:

```
$xml= new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('http://www.freegeoip.net/xml/{IP_or_hostname}'));
if($xml->CountryCode == "US") {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Chris. Yes - http://www.ip2location.com/ creates an htaccess file as per below example copied from the file it creates:      <Limit GET HEAD POST>
    order deny,allow
    allow from 2.16.9.0/24
    allow from 2.16.18.0/24
allow from 2.16.20.0/23
allow from 2.16.27.0/24
allow from 2.16.45.0/24
allow from 2.16.56.0/22   - I assume this is a bad approach?

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't the entire file since you said it was 4mb?

Comment: No - just a few lines - as you state - it has a defined list of IPs to allow based on ones it knows are in the 'allowed' country locations. It seems to work... I appreciate the major downside is the list is not updated as its a canned file - but will it be a slow performance? seems ok when I test..?

Comment: I wouldn't think you would suffer performance wise from that but how are you verifying that your code is reliably blocking requests from that country?

Comment: OK thanks Chris. That's the issue - the list of IPs is a list which I am relying on that ip2location.com have created is in some ways accurate... I guess they build their database with every visit to their site as they track the IP of all visitors. Your suggested solution would use a connection to a constantly updated database of IPs yes?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to block a visitor in web server. One is using firewall (.htaccess etc) and another one is using server-side scripting (PHP etc).

If you are concern of the performance of the firewall option, then you can download the IP2Location LITE database from http://lite.ip2location.com and implement the database in your local server. For every connection, you query the visitor IP address and find their country. You can redirect or block them using the PHP codes. Please find the complete steps in https://www.ip2location.com/tutorials/redirect-web-visitors-by-country-using-php-and-mysql-database

There is also another option to use remote geolocation API. However, we do not suggest this method because of network latency. It will slow down all user experience due to API queries.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I will have a look into this solution you recommend.